# Creating a custom checkbox

Tags: css, reactjs

I am trying to create a custom check box that has a transparent background and a border with a color of:#888. I have tried many different things but no cigar yet. I cant get rid of the white background.

```js
          <div className="form-checkbox">
              <div className="checkbox-unit">
                {" "}
                <input type="checkbox" /> Remember me
              </div>
            </div>
```

```css
.form-checkbox {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  text-align: left;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
.checkbox-unit {
  margin-top: 10px;
  
  
  
}
```

Comment: Hello Chickenwsiperer. Have you read the suggested question [How to style a checkbox using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-a-checkbox-using-css?rq=2)? It appears the answers there will answer your question as well.

Comment: I was able to get it thanks to your linke. Thanks @PatrickM.